# How to read data from text file using python2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, file

can anybody try to help me to retrieve numbers in Python and each number to an array: 
I have done the following code, it does the job but it reads 10 as two numbers:

```
with open("test.dat") as infile:
    for i, line in enumerate(infile):
        if i == 0:
            for x in range(0, len(line)):
                if(line[x] == ' ' or line[x] == "  "):
                    continue

                else:
                    print(x, " " , line[x], ", ")
                    initial_state.append(line[x])
```

---Results:

```
  (0, ' ', '1', ', ')
  (2, ' ', '2', ', ')
  (4, ' ', '3', ', ')
  (6, ' ', '4', ', ')
  (8, ' ', '5', ', ')
  (10, ' ', '6', ', ')
  (12, ' ', '7', ', ')
  (14, ' ', '8', ', ')
  (16, ' ', '9', ', ')
  (18, ' ', '1', ', ')
  (19, ' ', '0', ', ')
  (21, ' ', '1', ', ')
  (22, ' ', '1', ', ')
  (24, ' ', '1', ', ')
  (25, ' ', '2', ', ')
  (27, ' ', '1', ', ')
  (28, ' ', '3', ', ')
  (30, ' ', '1', ', ')
  (31, ' ', '4', ', ')
  (33, ' ', '1', ', ')
  (34, ' ', '5', ', ')
  (36, ' ', '0', ', ')
  (37, ' ', '\n', ', ')
```

index include spaces, please see the line of numbers im trying to add to array

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .split() to split all fields by looping through, please see the following code, it should do it

```
with open("test.dat") as infile:
       for i, line in enumerate(infile):
           if i == 0: # if first line
               field = [field.split(" ") for field in line.split(" ")]

               for x in range(0, len(field)):
                   initial_state_arr.append(field[x])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure each number is separated by a single space why not just split the line and print each element as an array:

```
with open("test.dat") as infile:
    content = infile.read().split()
    for index, number in enumerate(content):
        print ((index*2, number))
```

And what is your exact input and expected result? Does the file have multiple spaces between numbers?